# Unable to access [object Object] when passed through data-attribute

Tags: html, jquery, json

I have a JSON file stored inside a data attribute.

Now when on click, I want to access the values inside it but I am facing problem.

`var det = $(this).attr("data-details")`

This shows the type as `string` with the value`[object Object]`

I've tried different methods but can't seem to extract the values stored in it.

Also tried `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($(this).(attr("data-details"));`

Edit:

Method of populating the `data-details`

```
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var fileObj = JSON.parse(data[i][2]);
      $($idName)
      .append('<a><li id="asdf" class="list-group-item" data-details="'
      +fileObj
      +'" data-filename="'
      +data[i][0]
      +'">'
      +fileObj.description
      +'</li></a>');
    }
```

[image]

Comment: When using methods like `alert` it automatically calls `Object.prototype.toString()`, which results in `[object Object]`. Try using `JSON.stringify($(this).(attr("data-details")))`.

Comment: @quicVO I've tried it as well and it turns `[object Object]` into a string value `"[object Object]"`

Comment: Then that would be the result of you at some point turning it into a string. `{"json" : "json"}` as a string is `[object Object]`. Try using inspect element to see it the `dataset` attribute of `details` is `[object Object]`. If it is, this code is right, but somewhere else, something went wrong.

Comment: @quicVO yup the data attribute of `details` is `[object Object]`. I'll continue looking for solutions!

Comment: If you find what might be the problem, feel free to update the question and tag me ;)

Comment: @quicVOno problem! :)

Comment: _"This shows the type as"_... the code in your question shows nothing. What are you doing to produce `[object Object]` and where are you seeing it?

Comment: How is the data attribute populated? Is it in the HTML source or are you setting it via JS? Please include an example of how it is set

Comment: @Phil added! Thanks!